# DWR + Spring - Multiple ajax filters not working

Tags: java, spring, filter, dwr

Is there a problem defining more than one DWR (v2.0.5) ajax filter in a Spring (v2.5.1) configuration file?

For example:

```
<bean id="..." class="...">
    <dwr:remote javascript="...">
        <dwr:filter class="foo1"/>
        <dwr:filter class="foo2"/>
    </dwr:remote>
</bean>
```

In my case the only filter getting called is foo2, or more accurately the last filter in the list (checked this by switching filters around etc).

The strangest thing is I can't find anything about such a problem, I've tried Google and searching DWR's bug database both of which turned up nothing!

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Tried remote debugging? Useful tool in situations like this.

Comment: Yes, I debugged to verify only one filter was being called. Checking the AjaxFilterChain argument (see method signature at DWR site) in the Eclipse debugger I can see it contains a list which only has two elements, my filter first then a ExecuteAjaxFilter, which is a DWR filter that actually executes the method.

Answer (score 0):

This is a dwr's bug in `DwrNamespaceHandler.java`. It creates new list of filters on every discovery of `dwr:filter` tag.